# Is there a way to access the genres element

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, es6-promise, netflix

I am creating a Netflix clone and I used TMDB API to get data but I am facing this problem where when I try to access the data it shows undefined but when I log the JSON promise It shows up like this:

```
Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Object
```

[image: An Image format of object opened form]

This is the code:

```
let fetchDatas = [] // To store Json Data

const fetchData = async () => {
    let data = await fetch(`${baseURL}?api_key=${API_KEY}`); // baseURL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list' && API_KEY is private.

    if (data.status === 200) {
        return await data.json();
    }
}

fetchDatas = fetchData();
console.log(fetchDatas);

fetch(`${baseURL}?api_key=${API_KEY}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        fetchDatas = data;
    })

console.log(fetchDatas);
```

Whenever I use API's this problem occurs. How to solve this?

I need to access the promise JSON data and its elements. i.e.: `"fetchDatas['genres']` or `fetchDatas.genres` something like this or what ever way there is!"

so that I can implement it to my Netflix clone

Comment: No, In that case, it says the response is undefined. In my case, I did get the response back but when I accessed the elements in the response object it said undefined!

Comment: @InSync I need to access genres inside [[PromiseResult]]: Object and also the elements inside genres too. How can I do that? This is the simplified form of the above question!

Comment: I am confused as to why you are re-assigning `fetchDatas` in your `.then()` block. Why are there even two separate `fetch` calls?

Comment: Anyway moving the `console.log()` into the second `.then()` block should print your desired result.

Comment: @tobifasc  To show that I have tried both fetch().then() and async-await way too but both return the same thing and I'm asking how to access the object elements inside the promise.

Comment: @tobifasc Yes, It gives me the result like this: (Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Object ) But I don't know how to access the elements inside this ( 
[[PromiseResult]]: Object  ). So How to access them that is my question!

Comment: @JoyalGeorge You cannot access them without *waiting* for the promise.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are faced with, is a result of treating asynchronous code as synchronous. And that is a mistake. Please check out one of the links below to learn more about Promises (especially the ones from web.dev).

The following code, should demonstrate it better:

```js
console.log('First code line')
let result = []

console.log('Before fetch')
fetch(`${baseURL}?api_key=${API_KEY}`)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('Got data, convert to object')
      response.json()
    }).then(data => {
        console('Got json data')
        result = data;
    })

console.log('Before result')
console.log(result);
console.log('Last code line')
```

You will see that "Before result" and "Last code line" being printed before it even says "Got data, convert to object". As `fetch()` returns a promise, the code will continue to exec synchronously while the async code (the promise handlers `.then(...)` will be triggered only when the new data arrived (the promise fulfills or rejects). So a long as you cannot do a highlevel `await`, you have to deal with `then/catch` statements. A working code looks like this:

```js
function handleGenre(data) {
  // do with the api response what ever you like, like updating the GUI.
  console.table(data)
}

fetch(`${baseURL}?api_key=${API_KEY}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(handleGenre)
    .catch(e => console.error(e))
```

More about promises:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
- https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-promise-objects
- https://web.dev/articles/introduction-to-fetch?hl=en
- https://web.dev/articles/async-functions?hl=en